# ulimit -e in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, ulimit

What is the equivalent of this command in Solaris?

```
ulimit -e 19
```

What this does in other systems is set all programs in the current shell to run with `nice -n 19`.  When I try to run the above command in Solaris it does not recognise the `-e` option.

Comment: By "other systems" do you mean Linux? Becuase `-e` don't exist on Mac OS X nor OpenBSD.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are down votes.  It seems to be a very normal and relevant question.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to define the maximum priority for the processes under a user.
You can achieve this in Solaris via the `prioctnl` command.

> prioctnl -s -m 19 -i uid $uid

I don't have a Solaris box at hand but the man page can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/priocntl-1.html).

Also, if you want to make it permanent, the best way is to put it with a project. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19044-01/sol.containers/817-1592/rmtaskproj.task-10/index.html).

Comment: I am not an administrator.  Is it possible to run this command as a standard user to apply to the current shell?

Comment: it is possible, but it will depend on your rights.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you Learn to use the renice command.  You can do the same using the command:

```
 renice 19 -p <pid1 pid2 ... pidN>
```

In the local case running under a /bin/sh varient, use:

```
 renice 19 -p $$
```

this will change the nice level of the current shell to level 19.

Comment: I want to put the `ulimit` command in `.profile` so that it applies by default in every shell.  What you are suggesting doesn't achieve this.

Comment: @CJ7 It should do. The nice level is inherited from the login shell.